# Relative URL in the location header is not handled in HTTP client C#

Tags: c#, url, httpclient, http-status-codes

I used HTTP client to get the status of the URL. By Default the **AllowAutoRedirect is True**.

It automatically process the URL redirection. But it fails if the location header returns the absolute URL.

It stops the request and return last location header url status.

**Example:**

URL A ("http://www.alphabets.com/a") -> Redirect -> URL B ("http://www.alphabets.com/b")

URL B ("http://www.alphabets.com/b") -> Redirect -> URL C ("http://www.alphabets.com/c")

URL C ("http://www.alphabets.com/c") -> Redirect -> URL D ("http://www.alphabets.com/d")

URL D ("http://www.alphabets.com/d")-> Redirect -> URL E  ("/e") **(E is relative URL)**

URL D status code is returned as status code. But the actual Redirected URL is F.

is there any way to overcome this case and get URL F as the redirected one.

**Note:**

It can be achieved by setting **AllowAutoRedirect=false** and manually handle the redirection. But I want to find, is there any way to achieve this with **AllowAutoRedirect=True**

Comment: You’ve listed all http examples, but are some actually https?

Comment: It just a sample data for clarity. There might be a combination http and https or only http or only https urls received by the in the location header.

Comment: I suspect the redirects that remain within http or https (and all the relative paths would satisfy this), as well as the ones that redirect http -> https succeed, but the https -> http ones fail.  Can you confirm?